# Why does this code work and not produce a segmentation error?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Why doesn't this code give me segmentation error?
I've allocated only 1 char and yet I entered more than 1 char.

```
char **names;

names=malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
names[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*1) ;

names[0]="ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC";

printf("%s",names[0]);
```

I expected it should generate a segmentation error.

Comment: All you're doing is assigning memory addresses. There's no copying of the character data happening (You'd use something like `strcpy` for that).

Comment: Why do you think it should give `segfault`?

Comment: You're leaking the memory allocated by `malloc(sizeof(char)*1);`, but that's not going to cause a segmentation fault. On an unrelated note, `sizeof(char)` is always `1` so you can just shorten it to `malloc(1)` instead.

Comment: Explicitly asking for segmentation-fault is not considered a good learning strategy.

Comment: @machine_1 That depends, on the learning curriculum. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code

```
names[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*1) ;
names[0]="ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC";
```

you're basically overwriting the value of the variable `names[0]`, i.e, storing another pointer to it (the starting address of the string literal). There is no reason it should produce a segmentation fault. It will however, cause [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), as you're losing the original pointer returned by `malloc()` and will never get a chance to `free()` it.

OTOH, if you would have written something like

```
names[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*1) ;
strcpy(names[0], "ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC");
```

where you were trying to access memory location beyond the allocated boundary, you'll invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then also, segmentation fault is **one of the many** possible side effects, it's never guranteed.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is well formed, so there's no reason it should segfault.  Let's break things down:

```
char **names;
```

This declares a pointer to pointer to `char`.

```
names=malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
```

This allocates space for an array of `char *` of size 2 and assigns that address to `names`.

```
names[0]=malloc(sizeof(char)*1) ;
```

This allocates space for an array of `char` of size 1 and assigns that address to `names[0]`.

```
names[0]="ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC";
```

Here's where it gets interesting.  This assigns the address of the given string constant to `names[0]`, **overwriting** the address of the allocated memory that was assigned on the previous line.  This also leaks the memory allocated on the prior line.

```
printf("%s",names[0]);
```

This prints the string pointed to by `names[0]`.  Since it contains the address of the string literal `"ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC"`, that is what was printed.

Instead of assigning a string literal to `names[0]`, what you probably wanted to do was this:

```
strcpy(names[0], "ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC");
```

This would copy the contents of the string literal to `names[0]`, which only points to 1 byte of allocated memory.  A segfault here however is not guaranteed.

When you write past the end of allocated memory, you invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means the code may crash, it may output strange results, or it could appear to work properly.  Just because the code *might* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the other answers, a pointer to the first character in the string literal is assigned to `names[0]` rather than the string being copied into the allocated object. Also, if you assign a string literal to a character pointer variable, it should be declared as `const`.

When working in C, the programmer needs to create her own safety net. Below is an example of a function which terminates the program if the string to be assigned is too long.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])
#define NEW_ARRAY(ptr, n) (ptr) = malloc((n) * sizeof (ptr)[0])

static void Copy(const char source[], int sourceLen, char target[], int targetLen)
{
    if (targetLen >= sourceLen) {
        strcpy(target, source);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Copy failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    char source[] = "ATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATCCACTATCAHCTACHATC";
    char *target;
    int targetLen = 1;

    NEW_ARRAY(target, targetLen);
    Copy(source, LEN(source), target, targetLen);
    puts(target);
    return 0;
}
```